# PHP script in XAMPP shows gibberish

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, runtime-error

I wrote a simple PHP script to run with XAMPP:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
?>
```

The script is in htdocs, as test.php, XAMPP has a green light for the Apache and MySQL, and both local hosts have a green light. Also, I pressed mount under volumes.

However, when I put `http://localhost:8080/test.php` into my browser, all that shows up is this gibberish:

```
bookmark88P��������Ap4UsersMady  Documentstest.php ,@7�G^H^��hx��A���%���� file:///Macintosh HD`3A�ݨ�$575888D7-ADD6-32F5-908D-0B9414CCE3C2���/NSURLDocumentIdentifierKeyB3dnibphp????����P��@�T�UV� � , < p P ` �0 ��� � ��@"�����
```

What steps should I take to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it applies to MAC, but did you run the xampp setup script ? also, what encoding is your php file ? and what native system encoding ?

Comment: (Out of topic) this question lets me think of [xkcd: Types of Editors](https://xkcd.com/1341/)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reason when I dragged the file into the htdocs folder it was not working. I opened up another file in htdocs, in atom, which gave me the ability to edit test.php to make the code correct and not that gibberish. This is the correct answer, I just can't mark it yet if its not marked.